# Como conseguir el 'key' con el valor mas alto en un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python, y tengo el siguiente problema, debo conseguir el item con el valor mas alto de un diccionario.

```py
verse_dict =  {'if': 3, 'you': 6, 'can': 3, 'keep': 1, 'your': 1, 'head': 1, 'when': 2, 'all': 2, 'about': 2, 'are': 1, 'losing': 1, 'theirs': 1, 'and': 3, 'blaming': 1, 'it': 1, 'on': 1, 'trust': 1, 'yourself': 1, 'men': 1, 'doubt': 1, 'but': 1, 'make': 1, 'allowance': 1, 'for': 1, 'their': 1, 'doubting': 1, 'too': 3, 'wait': 1, 'not': 1, 'be': 1, 'tired': 1, 'by': 1, 'waiting': 1, 'or': 2, 'being': 2, 'lied': 1, 'don\'t': 3, 'deal': 1, 'in': 1, 'lies': 1, 'hated': 1, 'give': 1, 'way': 1, 'to': 1, 'hating': 1, 'yet': 1, 'look': 1, 'good': 1, 'nor': 1, 'talk': 1, 'wise': 1}
```

Intente esto `max(verse_dict.values())` que me retorna el valor pero no se como hacer para obtener el `key`

**POSIBLE RESPUESTA**

Este codigo me funciono, pero si hay **alguna manera de hacerlo mas efficiente** pues me gustaria saberla.

```py
result, val = 0, ''
for i, j in verse_dict.items():
    if result < j:
        result = j
        val = i
print(val)
```

Comment: `max(verse_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]`

Comment: Gracias, ya me investigo el `lambda` para poder desifrar tu implementacion

Comment: Perdón por el comentario tan sucinto y sin explicaciones. No estaba en el ordenador en ese momento. Acabo de escribir una respuesta explicando mejor todo esto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La función `max()` es mucho más potente y versátil de lo que parece, gracias a que se le puede pasar a través de su parámetro `key` una función en base a la cual se elegirá el máximo.

Lo que ocurre es que `max()` aplicará esa función a cada uno de los elementos del iterable cuyo máximo intentas obtener, y se quedará con aquél para el cual el resultado devuelto por la función sea el mayor posible.

Podemos usar esto en la forma siguiente. Primero, le pasas `verse_dict.items()` como iterable a la función `max()`. Como sabes esto producirá un iterable en el que cada elemento es una tupla `(clave, valor)`. Sin hacer uso del parámetro opcional `key`, `max()` irá comparando cada una de estas tuplas entre sí, para quedarse con la "mayor". Una tupla es mayor que otra si su primer elemento es mayor (y en caso de que sea igual, entonces mirará el segundo). Esto no nos vale porque la tupla resultante de esto será aquella que tenga el valor máximo en la `clave`, y no en el `valor`.

Pero si asignamos a `key` una función que retorne el segundo elemento de la tupla, entonces el máximo se computará según ese segundo elemento. En ese caso el valor resultante `(clave, valor)` será el que tenga el `valor` máximo.

La función que hace falta pasarle por tanto sería tan simple como esta:

```
def obtener_valor(tupla):
   return tupla[1]
```

Y por tanto podríamos llamar a `max()` de la siguiente forma `max(verse_dict.items(), key=obtener_valor)`. El resultado será la tupla `(clave, valor)` cuyo `valor` sea máximo. Basta quedarse con la clave:

```
val = max(verse_dict.items(), key=obtener_valor)[0]
```

Lo de la `lambda` es simplemente una forma de ahorrarse tener que escribir una función aparte y tener que inventarse un nombre para ella. Cuando la función que necesitas escribir es tan simple que se compone únicamente de un `return`, puedes escribirla en forma de `lambda` en el propio lugar donde la necesitas:

```
val = max(verse_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

En este caso la lambda recibe un solo parámetro `x`, que será cada uno de los elementos que hay en `verse_dict.items()`, y retornará `x[1]`, es decir, su valor. Observa que en la `lambda` no se pone `return`, sino simplemente la expresión que se desea retornar.

#### Bonus

El hecho de tener que escribir una lambda para quedarse con un elemento de una tupla es tan común, que en la biblioteca estándar Python proporciona una función para esto, muy útil para las funciones `max()`, `min()` o `sort()`, todas las cuales admiten el parámetro `key` en base al cual hacer las comparaciones.

En el módulo `operator` tienes la función `itemgetter()` al que le pasas como parámetro qué elemento de la tupla quieres y te retorna otra función que puedes usar en lugar de la lambda. Esa función retornada recibirá a su vez una tupla y retornará el elemento deseado de la misma.

Por ejemplo:

```
from operator import itemgetter

>>> max(verse_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
('you', 6)
```

### Versión aún más simple

**ChemaCortes** propone la siguiente solución, aún más simple:

```
>>> max(verse_dict, key=verse_dict.get)
'you'
```

Debo decir que estuve dándole vueltas a algo así pero no conseguí dar con ello ¡gracias Chema!

¿Cómo funciona este caso? A `max()` le estamos pasando `verse_dict`, en lugar de `verse_dict.items()`, por lo que en esta ocasión `max` iterará sólo por la lista de claves, en lugar de por la lista de `(clave,valor)`. El resultado por tanto será una clave directamente, lo que evita tener que aplicarle el `[0]` al resultado.

Para cada clave del diccionario, `max` llamará a la función especificada en el parámetro `key`. Así, a la primera clave obtenida le aplicará  `verse_dict.get(primera_clave)`, por lo que obtendrá su valor. Y así con cada una de las claves. Ya que son estos valores los usados en las comparaciones, el resultado final será la clave cuyo valor sea el máximo.

Comment: Todavía habría una forma más directa: `max(verse_dict, key=verse_dict.get)`

Comment: Gracias @ChemaCortes! He extendido la respuesta para explicar tu ingeniosa solución

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimada comunidad

Lo que me ha funcionado iteractuando con los elementos de los diccionarios es convertirlas a **listas** y utilizar el método **UPDATE** para actualizar los valores, luego hacer la lógica FOR.

Este es un ejemplo

```
diccionario={0: 2.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 6.0}

print ("Diccionario inicial",diccionario)

for  key,value in list(diccionario.items()):
    if value == max(diccionario.values()):
         diccionario.update({'max': value})
         del diccionario[key]
    elif value == min(diccionario.values()):
        diccionario.update({'min':value})
        del diccionario[key]     
    else:
        del diccionario[key]    

print ("Diccioanrio final",diccionario)
```

Nótese que en este caso de ejemplo "dropea" todos los otros valores que no son ni mayores ni menores, y sólo deja los MAX y MIN

```
Diccionario inicial {0: 2.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 6.0}
Diccioanrio final {'min': 2.0, 'max': 6.0}
```

Espero que les sea de utilidad